# Succinct form of inclusion only based on a condition?

Tags: single-word-requests

An example:

> The grouping contains regions of brightness, excluding ones with densities below the threshold

The opposite of *exclude* in this context would be *include only*, as in *including only ones with densities above the threshold*.

Is there any single word for this, instead of *include only*?

Comment: '[C]ontains regions of brightness, including only ones with densities below the threshold' doesn't sound idiomatic. I'd want a contrastive here: 'Contains regions of brightness, but only ones with densities below the threshold'.

Comment: This will help you save more words (may or may not be what you want): `The grouping contains regions of brightness, denoting [including only the ones with] densities above the threshold`.

Comment: Note that *excluding ones with X* is still imprecise, in that you may also exclude some without X. In terms of wording for inclusion, I would just shorten the sentence with the condition: *The grouping contains regions of brightness with densities above the threshold.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exclusively ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exclusively)):

> limiting or limited to possession, control, or use by a single individual or group

You could say:

> The grouping exclusively contains regions of brightness with densities above the threshold.

You can also exclude *include only*:

> The grouping contains regions of brightness with densities above the threshold.